# Dynamically add a directive with a ng-click inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDIT: plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/fHPQfbUQ1lvZBJsDNQR5/

I got a problem when I append my directive in my html, I have an error:

`"http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=17&p3=updateTypeZone(%7B%7Bcount%7D%7D)&p4=%7Bcount%7D%7D"` when I click on the button.

my code: ( here my controller )

```
connectItApp.controller('Inputcontroller',['$scope','$http', '$compile' , function($scope, $http, $compile) {
 $scope.count = 1;

 $scope.addInput = function(){

  angular.element(document.getElementById('box')).append($compile("<new></new>")($scope));
  $scope.count++;
 }

 $scope.updateTypeZone = function (concernedId) {
    /*some stuff */
}]);
```

(here my two directives they are called in a div witch as Inputcontroller as controller)

```
connectItApp.directive('champText', function(){
 return{
  restrict: 'E',
  template:     '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="addInput()" >'+
  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Text</span>'+
  '</button>'

 };
});

connectItApp.directive('new', function($compile){
 return{
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'views/new-input.html'

 };
});
```

(and here views/new-input.html)

```
<div ng-click='updateTypeZone({{count}})'>toto</div>
```

My goal is when I click on the button, I want that a new div append in the  like this exemple:

If I click one time , I will have

```
<div id="box"><div ng-click='updateTypeZone(1)'></div></div>
```

If I click a second time, I will have

```
<div id="box"><div ng-click='updateTypeZone(1)'></div><div ng-click='updateTypeZone(2)'></div></div>
```

etc..

I don't know how I can solve my problem.

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker which will reproduced the issue?

Comment: yep I just did one

Comment: On a side note, it's not a good idea to manipulate the dom inside a controller, only a directive should do that.

Comment: that means ? ( I'm use to use directive with angular but I'm sure that I use it really bad )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember your view is just a represenation of your controller. Instead of adding the html to the dom manually you would simply add it to your template with `ng-repeat` and adjust the controller.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.count += 1;
  };
  $scope.range = function() {
    var input = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.count; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "app" ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in range()">listing {{ n }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm creating a kind of formular creator like we can see on internet. My code here is really simplify, I want append with the same technique some img, select etc etc.. Which are draggable, and editable etc etc.. Can I do that using your solution? cause I already did my formular creator using some directive but I find the code really bad. I don't know the best way to develop that type of program.

Comment: instead of just increasing the count, you can add objects to an array, which contains information like 'type', 'position' ect. Then you use ng-switch to display the content depending on type. The idea is the same.